# How to extract lines after specific words?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, findall

I want to get date and specific item in a text using regular expression in python 3. Below is an example:

```
text = '''
190219 7:05:30 line1 fail
               line1 this is the 1st fail
               line2 fail
               line2 this is the 2nd fail
               line3 success 
               line3 this is the 1st success process
               line3 this process need 3sec
200219 9:10:10 line1 fail
               line1 this is the 1st fail
               line2 success 
               line2 this is the 1st success process
               line2 this process need 4sec
               line3 success 
               line3 this is the 2st success process
               line3 this process need 2sec

'''
```

In the example above, I would like to get all line after 'success line'. Here desired output:

```
[('190219','7:05:30','line3 this is the 1st success process', 'line3 this process need 3sec'),
('200219', '9:10:10', 'line2 this is the 1st success process', 'line2 this process need 4sec', 'line3 this is the 2st success process','line3 this process need 2sec')]
```

This is want I've tried:

```
>>> newLine = re.sub(r'\t|\n|\r|\s{2,}',' ', text)
>>> newLine
>>> Out[3]: ' 190219 7:05:30 line1 fail  line1 this is the 1st fail  line2 fail  line2 this is the 2nd fail  line3 success line3 this is the 1st success process  line3 this process need 3sec 200219 9:10:10 line1 fail  line1 this is the 1st fail  line2 success line2 this is the 1st success process  line2 this process need 4sec  line3 success line3 this is the 2st success process  line3 this process need 2sec  '
```

I don't know what the proper way to get result. I've tried this to get the line :

```
(\b\d{6}\b \d{1,}:\d{2}:\d{2})...
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Does everything have to be done in strictly regex? Can part of the solution not be regex?

Comment: No, it doesn't not. I'm just mentioned what I've tried. I do not know other ways @kosayoda

Comment: How about this pattern: [`^(\d[ \d:]+\d)(?:.*\n\B)*?.*success.*\n((?:\B.*\n?)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/QVhrPe/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses regex to get the date, and regular Python to get everything else.

Prepare the input:

```py
text = '''
190219 7:05:30 line1 fail
               line1 this is the 1st fail
               line2 fail
               line2 this is the 2nd fail
               line3 success
               line3 this is the 1st success process
               line3 this process need 3sec
200219 9:10:10 line1 fail
               line1 this is the 1st fail
               line2 success
               line2 this is the 1st success process
               line2 this process need 4sec
               line3 success
               line3 this is the 2st success process
               line3 this process need 2sec
'''

# Strip the multiline string, split into lines, then strip each line
lines = [line.strip() for line in text.strip().splitlines()]
result = parse(lines)
```

Solution:

```py
import re

def parse(lines):
    result = []
    buffer = []

    success = False
    for line in lines:
        date = re.match(r"(\d{6})\s(\d{1,}:\d{2}:\d{2})", line)
        if date:
            # Store previous match and reset buffer
            if buffer:
                result.append(tuple(buffer))
                buffer.clear()
            # Split the date and time and add to buffer
            buffer.extend(date.groups())
        # Check for status change
        if line.endswith("success") or line.endswith("fail"):
            success = True if line.endswith("success") else False
        # Add current line to buffer if it's part of the succeeded process
        else:
            if success:
                buffer.append(line)
    # Store last match
    result.append(tuple(buffer))
    return result
```

Output:

```py
result = [('190219', '7:05:30', 'line3 this is the 1st success process', 'line3 this process need 3sec'), ('200219', '9:10:10', 'line2 this is the 1st success process', 'line2 this process need 4sec', 'line3 this is the 2st success process', 'line3 this process need 2sec')]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution using regex:

```
text = '''
190219 7:05:30 line1 fail
               line1 this is the 1st fail
               line2 fail
               line2 this is the 2nd fail
               line3 success 
               line3 this is the 1st success process
               line3 this process need 3sec
200219 9:10:10 line1 fail
               line1 this is the 1st fail
               line2 success 
               line2 this is the 1st success process
               line2 this process need 4sec
               line3 success 
               line3 this is the 2st success process
               line3 this process need 2sec
'''

# find desired lines
count = 0
data = []
for item in text.splitlines():
    # find date
    match_date = re.search('\d+\s\d+:\d\d:\d\d', item)
    # get date
    if match_date != None:
        count = 1
        date_time = match_date.group().split(' ')
        for item in date_time:
            data.append(item)
    # find line with success
    match = re.search('\w+\d\ssuccess',item)
    # handle collecting next lines
    if match != None:
        count = 2

    if count > 2:
        data.append(item.strip())

    if count == 2:
        count += 1

# split list data
# find integers i list
numbers = []
for item in data:
     numbers.append(item.isdigit())

# get positions of integers
indexes = [i for i,x in enumerate(numbers) if x == True]
number_of_elements = len(data)
indexes = indexes + [number_of_elements]

# create list of list
result = []
for i in range(0, len(indexes)-1):
    result.append(data[indexes[i]:indexes[i+1]])
```

Result:

```
[['190219', '7:05:30', 'line3 this is the 1st success process', 'line3 this process need 3sec'], ['200219', '9:10:10', 'line2 this is the 1st success process', 'line2 this process need 4sec', 'line3 this is the 2st success process', 'line3 this process need 2sec']]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the similar solution by using [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from itertools:

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

def parse(lines):
    result = []
    buffer, success_block = [], False
    for date, block in groupby(lines, key=lambda l: re.match(r"(\d{6})\s(\d{1,}:\d{2}:\d{2})", l)):
        if date:
            buffer = list(date.groups())
            success_block = next(block).endswith('success')
            continue
        for success, b in groupby(block, key=lambda l: re.match(r".*line\d\ssuccess$", l)):
            if success:
                success_block = True
                continue
            if success_block:
                buffer.extend(b)

        result.append(tuple(buffer))
        buffer = []
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer more functional and elegant code, then the below code should work. I have used a functional library in python called [toolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.partition). You can install it by doing `pip install toolz`. The below code does not use any regex, but just uses `partitions` and `filters`. Please change the `input_file` with your file containing the text and try.

```
from toolz import partitionby, partition
from itertools import dropwhile

input_file = r'input_file.txt'


def line_starts_empty(line):
    return line.startswith(' ')


def clean(line):
    return line.strip()


def contains_no_success(line):
    return 'success' not in line.lower()


def parse(args):
    head_line, tail_lines = args
    result_head = head_line[0].split()[:2]
    result_tail = list(map(clean, dropwhile(contains_no_success, tail_lines)))
    return result_head + result_tail


for item in map(parse, partition(2, partitionby(line_starts_empty, open(input_file)))):
    print(item)
```